# when selecting vertex using has('prop', 'value') with injected 'value'

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

Is it possible to select vertex properties using injected values?

I can't use lambda that provided in the official doc: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#inject-step since the lambda is not supported in our case.

I tried doing

```
g.inject('vadas').as('a').V().has('name', select('a'))
```

but it's returning all the vertices that have attribute 'name', seems like it's not selecting the injected value

Are there any ways I can do the 'has' filter based on some injected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is supposed to return all vertices that have a `name` property, as `select('a')` should always return a value.

There is no way to use injected values and at the same time benefit from an index lookup. The only thing you can do is a full vertex scan:

```
gremlin> g.inject('vadas').as('a').V().where(eq('a')).by('name').by()
==>v[2]
```

That works well on a small in-memory graph, but it surely isn't a scalable solution.

**UPDATE**

If nested `select()`'s are not available, you could still do something like this:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]

gremlin> data = ["marko": ["title": "dr", "age": 40]]
==>marko={title=dr, age=40}

gremlin> g.V().has("person","name",within(data.keySet())).as("v").
           flatMap(constant(data).unfold().
                   where(eq("v")).
                     by(keys).
                     by("name").
                   select(values).
                   unfold()).as("kv").
           select("v").
             property(select("kv").by(keys), select("kv").by(values)).
           iterate()
gremlin> 
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[marko],title:[dr],age:[40]]
...
```

There is a full scan in this traversal, but only over the `data` memory structure. Hence, if `data` isn't crazy large, the traversal performance should/could be acceptable.

Comment: Got it, thanks Daniel! but I was trying to update multiple vertices properties, I can do either inject(prop) -> select(v) based on prop -> update, (this couldn't work now), or I can do inject(prop, vertex) -> update vertex from injected value, like this: (prop map key is vertex id, value is another hashmap contains all the properties: {'vertexId': {'name': 'Huimin', 'age': 24}}), I tried using g.inject(prop).as(‘a’).V(vertexList).unfold().as(‘b’).property(‘name’, __.select(‘a’).unfold().select(__.select(‘b’).id()).unfold().select(‘name’)), but it throws could not locate method exception..

Comment: I'm guessing it should be a quite common case when people are trying to update a big chunks of vertices with different properties? Are there any suggested solutions? I tried a lot of ways didn't succeed and didn't find any answers as well..

Comment: Well, I guess the exception is your biggest problem then. Support for nested `select()`'s was added in `3.3.3` and `3.4.0`. Whatever provider implementation you're using, is probably built on top an older version of TinkerPop.

Comment: ok... so the way I inject property Maps and use V(vertexList) and select property values based on the vertex id would actually work? I thought it's because of incompatible type of T.id and string or something..but actually I tried using unique property as key, eg: use 'age' as key, other props {'name': 'H', 'A': 'a'} as value, and do  g.inject(map).as('a').V(v).as('v').property('A', select('a').unfold().select(select('v').properties('age').value()).unfold().select('A')) still throws the same exception,,

Comment: I'm using neptune but not sure about the versions, I'll check. So there's nothing wrong with the query I used?

Comment: In the versions I've mentioned before, your query should just work. And yeah, CosmosDB and Neptune are always a bit behind the current TinkerPop version.

Comment: I added an example that shows what you can do if `select(select(...))` is not available.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! However I tried the approach but still didn't work in Neptune, the vertices properties are not updated, I tried in local gremlin it works well. I guess I'll have to concatenating long traversals and update their properties one by one... Really don't see any other ways.. Maybe batch processing would be a good option if I do long traversal? But since it's write operation, would it actually benefit on the performance?

Comment: Ohh sorry it's not just not working in Neptune, it's not working when I'm using Java.. I used in groovy it works but in java it doesn't. I used exactly same thing.. g.V().has("email", P.within(list)).as("v").flatMap(_ _.constant(maps).unfold().where(P.eq("v")).by(Column.keys).by("email").select(Column.values).unfold()).as("kv").select("v").property(_ _.select("kv").by(Column.keys), ___.select("kv").by(Column.values)) and it returned nothing. I tested g.V().has("email", P.within(emailList)).as("v").limit(1).constant(maps).unfold().where(P.eq("v")).by(Column.keys).by("email") and returns nothing

Comment: There's really no difference between Groovy and Java. If the underlying Graph database and TinkerPop version are the same, the result will be the same, too. Double-check that you're really doing the same thing.

Comment: yea the syntax is exactly the same.. unless .by("email") not working in java.. but I changed to by(_ _.values("emails")) still nothing..

Comment: this is really weird.. I did g.inject(1).constant('marko').as('v').constant(data).unfold().where(eq('v')).by(keys).by() in groovy and works fine, but in java this just doesn't return anything, I used the same version of tinkerpop, is it because of 'data' is List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> in java? otherwise there's no other difference.. Here is java code: g.inject(1).constant("marko").as("v").constant(data).unfold().where(P.eq("v")).by(Column.keys).by().toList()

Comment: Please create a Gist containing your whole Java program.

Comment: So, you're in fact not doing the same thing as in Groovy. Here's a working program: https://github.com/dkuppitz/huimin

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Kuppitz and @Huimin Yang, we have supported this feature, use property index scan, I think it will provide a  useful ability

```
gremlin> g.inject('vadas').as('a').V().has('name', eq(select('a'))).profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
InjectStep([vadas])@[a]                                                1           1           0.090     0.51
GraphDbGraphStep(vertex,[name.eq([SelectOneStep...                     1           1          17.768    99.49
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -          17.859        -
gremlin> g.inject('vadas').as('a').V().has('name', eq(select('a')))
==>v[vadas]
```